# Rotating a sprite with Touch - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I know this question has been asked several times, trust me I have searched. I have found one answer to rotating a sprite with touch, but there has to be a simpler way.

All I need is for my sprite to rotate with my touch. Max rotation 0 Minimum rotation 0.

I know that I'll need a few checks.

```
int maxRot = 0;
int minRot = 0;

    if (arrowRotation > maxRot)
    {
    //do or don't do something
    } else if (arrowRotation < minRot)
    {
    //do or don't do something
    }
```

Can someone lead me in the right direction to rotating a sprite with touch, with a minimun and maximum rotation?

Here is the code that I think is to complicated or can be accomplished in a simpler way.

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //acquire the previous touch location
    CGPoint firstLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    //preform all the same basic rig on both the current touch and previous touch
    CGPoint touchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    CGPoint firstTouchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:firstLocation];

    CGPoint firstVector = ccpSub(firstTouchingPoint, _arrow.position);
    CGFloat firstRotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(firstVector);
    CGFloat previousTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(firstRotateAngle);

    CGPoint vector = ccpSub(touchingPoint, _arrow.position);
    CGFloat rotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(vector);
    CGFloat currentTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rotateAngle);

    //keep adding the difference of the two angles to the dial rotation
    arrowRotation += currentTouch - previousTouch;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a link to the solution you think is too complicated - it might be the only way ;)

Comment: I updated my question with the code!

Comment: what do you mean by maxRot and minRot both are = 0 .

Comment: The minimum and maximum degrees that the arrow can turn to

Comment: Does your code work?  It looks ok.  If it works well, then don't worry about trying to make it "simpler".  If there are problems then you can tweak it until it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can simplify the rotation into anything simpler. I honestly didnt get how you want to both the minimum and the maximum rotations to be zero. They cant be same value. If you want to limit the rotation to a maximum and minimum add the following to the end of your `ccTouchesMoved:` method:

```
if (arrowRotation >= maxRot) {

    arrowRotation = maxRot; 
}

else if (arrowRotation <= minRot) {

    arrowRotation = minRot;
}
```

Comment: the minimum and maximum rotation where just examples. Both of them will not be 0.

Answer (score 0):

use `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer`...

```
KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer *rotation;

rotation = [[KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotating:)];
[[self Wheel] addGestureRecognizer:rotation];
[rotation release];
```

Method

```
- (void)rotating:(KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    view = [recognizer view];
    if(isRotating == FALSE) {
        [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([view transform], [recognizer rotation])];
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't setTransform to a CCsprite.